# Find cell containing greater 255 characters

Tags: vba, excel

My code below works perfectly to find a cell on a different worksheet when the string is small, however large text strings pull up an error.  I have tried using error handling even just to give a `MsgBox` rather than open a VBA window when it errors.

Can anyone help, preferably find the cell with many characters or if not possible, put an error handler in to say something like, *too large to search*.

What the code does, is a have a range of cells with text in each cell.  I can click on that cell, or a cell 2 columns to the right, then click the `FIND` button, to go in the next worksheet to find the exact same cell value.  All cells are unique.

```
Sub Find_Cell()

    Dim NA As Worksheet
    Set NA = Worksheets("Notes Analysis")

    LastRow = NA.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("G19:G" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then

        Dim value As String                      'Declare a string
        value = ActiveCell.Offset(, -2)          'Get the value of the selected Cell
        Dim ws As Worksheet

        'ws is the worksheet from we are searching the value
        'You have to change myWorkSheetName for you worksheet name
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DEBT_SALE_ACTIVITY")

        ws.Activate
        Dim c As Range                           'Declare a cell
        Set c = ws.Cells.Find(value, LookIn:=xlValues) 'Search the value

        If Not c Is Nothing Then                 'If value found
            c.Activate                           'Activate the cell, select it
        Else
            MsgBox "Not found"                   'shows a message "Not Found"
        End If
    Else

        If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("E19:E" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then

            Dim value2 As String                 'Declare a string
            value2 = ActiveCell                  'Get the value of the selected Cell
            Dim ws2 As Worksheet

            'ws is the worksheet from we are searching the value
            'You have to change myWorkSheetName for you worksheet name
            Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DEBT_SALE_ACTIVITY")

            ws2.Activate

            Dim c2 As Range                      'Declare a cell
            Set c2 = ws2.Cells.Find(value2, LookIn:=xlValues) 'Search the value

            If Not c2 Is Nothing Then            'If value found
                c2.Activate                      'Activate the cell, select it
            Else
                MsgBox "Not found"               'shows a message "Not Found"
            End If

        Else

            MsgBox "Select an Account Note"

        End If                                   'end the If for if active cell is in our notes
    End If                                       'end the If for if active cell is in Account note

End Sub
```

Comment: Not related to the issue, but you could use `value = ActiveCell.EntireRow.Range("E1")` for both of your two blocks of code, and thus combine the two blocks into one block.

Comment: Great idea, I did not realise I could go that but that advice does really help.  That way the active cell could be on any cell in the row yet still search for the cell in column E, plus halve the size of my code :)  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To provide an error message indicating the text is too long you could do the following:

Add this after each statement where you assign value its value:

```
value = ActiveCell.Offset(, -2) 'Get the value of the selected Cell
If Len(value) > 255 Then
    MsgBox "Text in cell " & CStr(ActiveCell.Address) & " is too long", vbOKOnly, "Search Text Too Long"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Also, you might want to change your if...then...else code structure.

Currently your code is operating like this:

```
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("G19:G" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then 
    do things
    exit sub
Else
    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("E19:E" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
        do things
        exit sub
    Else 
        MsgBox "Select an Account Note" 
        exit sub
```

Which, based on your comments for your End If's isn't exactly what your message box says.  If your first if statement is Account Notes and your second if statement is notes, then a better structure would be the following.

Change this code

```
Else

    If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("E19:E" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
```

To look like this

```
ElseIf Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("E19:E" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
```

Then the statement `MsgBox "Select an Account Note" will be accurate.  You also be able to delete one of your End If statements.

Your code will operate like this:

```
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("G19:G" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then 
    do things
    exit sub
ElseIf Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("E19:E" & LastRow)) Is Nothing Then
    do things
    exit sub
Else 
    MsgBox "Select an Account Note" 
    exit sub
```